# canvas drawimage loop with timeouts

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas, stream

I am trying to write a little streaming client with the canvas object.

This is the necessary code:

```
this.drawPictures = function() {
    var i = 0;

    while (i <= 3000) {
        this.addPicture("Pictures/Wildlife/" + i + '.bmp', 1, 1);
        i = i + 4;
    }
}
```

This works fine! The images are gonna displayed. But it's not what I want.

I want to set a FPS Limit. So I need to have a "sleep" of 1000ms/frames in this loop.

I have tried some methods with SetInterval or SetTimeOut. But none of them worked for me.

So I tried to write my own sleep:

```
    var i = 0;
    timeStart = new Date().getTime();

    while (i <= 3000) {
        timeNow = new Date().getTime();
        timeDifference = timeNow - timeStart;
        if (timeDifference > 1000*i) {
            this.addPicture("Pictures/Wildlife/" + i + '.bmp', 1, 1);
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
```

I save the actual Datetime before looping and exactly when the timedifference reaches 1000ms I am trying to load a picture and increment i.

My problem:
When I do this with alert(i) instead of this.addPicture it works fine! I get an alert every 1000ms (every second)

When I do it like the example above (with this.addPicture) the browser is just loading itself til i get an error that the page couldn't be loaded. But I dont see any pictures!

Here is my addPicture function:

```
this.addPicture = function (cPicPath, nSizeX, nSizeY) {

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function () {

        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, nSizeX, nSizeY);
    }
    imageObj.src = cPicPath;
}
```

Does anybody know why it works with alert but not with addPicture? Because when I don't use timestamps (first code example) it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

In your ctx.drawImage the 2 arguments after the imageObj are X/Y not image size.

You need to give sufficient time for your image to load (1 second isn't enough time).

Your addPicture **starts (but doesn't finish) loading an image**, but the image isn't fully loaded by the time addPicture is called again.

There are many image loaders out there...here's one:

```
var imageURLs=[];  // put the paths to your images here
var imagesOK=0;
var imgs=[];
imageURLs.push("myPicture1.png");
imageURLs.push("myPicture2.png");
imageURLs.push("myPicture3.png");
imageURLs.push("myPicture4.png");
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    // the imgs[] array holds fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]
    // Start your timer and display your pictures with addPicture

}
```